# Multiple taxonomies in single field

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Is there a module that allows you to combine two taxonomies?

Lets say I have the two simple taxonomies listed below.

Award:

- gold
- silver
- bronze

Year:

- 2012
- 2011
- 2010

Is there a module that allows me to add different deltas like "Gold+2012" and "Silver+2010" to the same field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module.

> Computed Field is a very powerful CCK field module that lets you add a custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the current user, database tables, you name it. […] You can also choose whether to store your computed field values in the database with other content fields, or have them "calculated" on the fly during node views.